# Unable to set a data property in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am unable to set the value for a data property for a Vue object. Here is my vue object:

```
   var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#divVM',
      data: {
        new_result_count: 0,
          result_count: 0,            
        rows:[],
        asc_sortorder:true,
        isLoading: false,
        enablePaginationControls: false,
        enableFirst: false,
        enablePrev: false,
        enableNext: false,      
        enableLast: false,
        middleSpan: '',

      },

      methods: {
            paginationControl: function(){
        //....
     }, 
  });
```

In my code, I set the value for vm.result_count, however, it always gets reset to 0 when I examine in console. Even if I set the value for vm.result_count in console, it changes back to 0. This is what I see in Console

```
vm.result_count = 23
23
vm.result_count 
0
```

Surprisingly, sometimes, when I am unable to set data for vm.result_count, the same for vm.new_result_count, it works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that element being used anywhere in the page? Any `v-model`s with it? Any computed property of the same name? Any timers working in the background resetting it?

Comment: Yes, that element is being used to control display of a division through v-show. No v-model and computed properties are being used.

Comment: After I commented code where vm.result_count and vm,new_result_count were being updated, I am able to at least correctly set the values for these  in Console.

Answer (score 0):

To control the display of a division, I incorrectly used v-show as 
v-show="**result_count=0**", instead of v-show="**result_count==0**". This was resetting the value of vm.result_count.